# What is the name called for the "functions" that are used after "getElementById"

Tags: javascript, html

So, my question is, for example: "document.getElementById("nameId").textContent = message;" I would like to know if there is a list of all the functions that can be used after the "getElementById" function. I dont have the exact key word to search up for on the internet.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement and its many, many subclasses.

Comment: Since you're asking for a *name*, it's commonly referenced to as the *element API*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called *properties* of an *element* object.

In your example, this is most likely a a *HTML DOM Element* object.

See:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Your code `document.getElementById("nameId")` is designed to return (or, as in that example, manipulate) an *element* object, for example a *HTML DOM Element* object.

If you wanted to just return it, you could put it into a variable, for example:

```
somevarible = document.getElementById("nameId")
```

Then you could refer to the variable for a myriad of reasons, including to manipulate the element.

Or you could return a property of the element into a variable, like this:

```
somevarible = document.getElementById("nameId").textContent
```

... the list goes on.

For the actual list, see [HTML Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement#properties)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `document.getElementById()` returns an `Element`, which is usually an `HTMLElement`, more specifically something like `HTMLDivElement` (depending on the tag returned). But it could also be an `SVGElement`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so, basically if I have the function: 
function showMessage("message"){
      document.getElementById("id").textContent = message;
}

When we say it "returns" does that mean that the .textContent returns the message into the function? So when we call the function it will contain what we have returned as textContent?

Comment: Let's take a step back here. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Is your original question just about learning, or do you have a specific task you are trying to accomplish with that information? To clarify 'returns', I have added a clarification in the answer.

Comment: @ed2  I'm just trying to clear things out, the thing is when I go to the page https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp , everyone of this properties says that they "return", return where and what is the structure?

Comment: It means you can "return" or "look up" or "read" or "discover" that property's current setting (or value or content or... etc). See the answer for how to do this.

Comment: @ed2 Okay, last question, what about if I don't want a variable and just use a function where will the return statement appear?

Comment: When your code is run, the program will interpret that part of the code as though it says the returned answer. For example, if you read through your code replacing `document.getElementById("nameId").textContent` with the actual text content of that element, that's how it will be interpreted. What happens to the returned property, how/if it is used, where/if it appears, etc, depends on what code you write and what your code does with the element property.